# D3.js Group text elements by class - make them hidden and visible

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3 rookie here

I have a lot of text elements. I want to make some appear when I click one button, some others disappear and the opposite when clicking another.

Problem is I can only reference them one by one by their variable names and fail when it comes to referencing them by their class.

I would like to write less code so I am here for some help!

Text elements:

```
   var text1 = svg.append("text")
     .attr("class",'appearing_text')
     .attr('visibility','hidden')
     .attr("x", 30)
     .attr("y", 55)
     .text("Blah")

   var text2 = svg.append("text")
     .attr("class",'appearing_text')
     .attr('visibility','hidden')
     .attr("x", 30)
     .attr("y", 255)
     .text("Non-Blah")
```

Then we make them visible on clicking a button [This works]

```
    d3.select("#button1").on('click', function(){
            text1("visibility", "visible").enter(text1)
            text2("visibility", "visible").enter(text2)
    })
```

and make them hide again with another [This also works]

```
    d3.select("#button2").on('click', function(){
            text1("visibility", "hidden").enter(text1)
            text2("visibility", "hidden").enter(text2)

    })
```

I tried this, but instead it broke all my script [Does not work]

```
    d3.select("#button1").on('click', function(){
       .selectAll('.appearing_text').style("visibility", "visible").enter()
```

Comment: Make their classes functions that return something specific to each set. Something like `.attr("class", function(d){return "appearing_text" + d.text})` would give them the class `appearing_text` and whatever `d.text` returns for each element.

Comment: And then run    d3.select("#button1").on('click', function(){
       .selectAll('.appearing_text').style("visibility", "visible").enter()

Tried it after changing the class to your code and then broke the script

Comment: Could you post a working example we can work off?

Comment: Excuse me, how do you post code that appears in grey? I am trying to make this easier.

Comment: I mean like a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something

Comment: Here you go sir https://jsfiddle.net/12mofjan/5/